# Change the same bool in a class with player input from multiple different keys

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a small space game, and I wanted to activate the same thruster with multiple keys. This is so I can activate multiple thrusters with one key input.

This was the solution I came up with. However, when I assign the same instance of the thruster script more than one key code, it stops functioning. I am not receiving any errors, and it is detecting the input.

I know I am missing something, but I just can't seem to find the answer since I don't even know where the problem lies. Thank you all in advance for your help.

```
    public List<ThrusterConfig> ThrusterConfigs = new List<ThrusterConfig>();

    [Serializable]
    public class ThrusterConfig
    {
        public Thruster thruster;
        public KeyCode[] keyCodes;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        foreach(ThrusterConfig config in ThrusterConfigs)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < config.keyCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                SetThrustersActive(config.keyCodes[i], config);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetThrustersActive(KeyCode keyCode, ThrusterConfig config)
    {
        foreach(KeyCode key in config.keyCodes)
        {
            config.thruster.IsActive = Input.GetKey(key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work for you. The change in the logic is to not assign the result from every key to the thruster but instead to figure out if any key is down and then assign that.

Perhaps you have 3 keys set in a config (a, b, c) and a is pressed. In your current logic a is checked and the thruster is set to active, then b is checked and it is turned off, then c is checked and it is turned off.

This logic assumes the thruster will be turned off by default but if any key is down it will turn it on instead and skip checking the rest of the keys since they don't matter.

```
public List<ThrusterConfig> ThrusterConfigs = new List<ThrusterConfig>();

[Serializable]
public class ThrusterConfig
{
    public Thruster thruster;
    public KeyCode[] keyCodes;
}

private void Update()
{
    foreach (ThrusterConfig config in ThrusterConfigs)
    {
        UpdateThruster(config);
    }
}

public void UpdateThruster(ThrusterConfig config)
{
    bool anyKeyDown = false;
    foreach (KeyCode key in config.keyCodes)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(key))
        {
            anyKeyDown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    config.thruster.IsActive = anyKeyDown;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your solution works great. I've been working on this simple problem for a way too long and you explaining it to me made me feel relived and angry at myself at the same time. I have used unity too long for this to be something I would miss. Hopefully, this will be a good lesson for me to look over my logic in more detail in the future.